# Python Pandas conditional transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

My datas look like this

```
Plate LogRatio
 1      0.4
 1      0.3
 1      0.2
 2      0.5 
 2      0.3
```

I would like to do 3 types of mean of LogRatio **by plate** : I don't want to count extremes LogRatio in my mean (quantiles exclusions).

```
m1 = mean(LogRatio[LogRatio > q20LogRatio & LogRatio < q80LogRatio])
m2 = mean(LogRatio[LogRatio > q25LogRatio & LogRatio < q75LogRatio])
m3 = mean(LogRatio[LogRatio > q30LogRatio & LogRatio < q70LogRatio])
M = (m1 + m2 + m3) / 3
```

I tried something like this :

```
df['m1'] = df.groupby('Plate')['LogRatio'].transform(lambda x: ((x > x.quantile(q=0.20)) & (x < x.quantile(q=0.80))).mean())
df['m2'] = df.groupby('Plate')['LogRatio'].transform(lambda x: ((x > x.quantile(q=0.25)) & (x < x.quantile(q=0.75))).mean())
df['m3'] = df.groupby('Plate')['LogRatio'].transform(lambda x: ((x > x.quantile(q=0.30)) & (x < x.quantile(q=0.70))).mean())
df['M'] = (df['m1'] + df['m2'] + df['m3']) / 3
```

But the results for each mean are not the same if I do it by hand on Calc.
Is it my logical conditions in the transform function that can't be understand like that ? I know the results are wrong but there isn't "Error" in my terminal so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Seems like you need `Groupby.apply` and not `transform` because you are filtering the groups and applying the function only to those many elements satisfying the condition. On the other hand,`Transform` works on the entire series. Maybe, that's what's causing erroneous values.

Comment: `Groupby.apply` fill "NaN" everywhere in my new columns. And I want to apply the function to all my lines because I create new columns in my dataframe, that's why I thought `transform` was ok but yes you're right that I get the mean from elements satisfying the condition and after applying the mean for every line in my new column. Anyway `apply` don't even give me numbers, just "NaN".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIU I would change the lambda function as follows:

```
df.groupby('Plate')['LogRatio'].transform(lambda s: s.loc[[True if v < s.quantile(q=0.8) and v > s.quantile(q=0.2) else False for v in s]].mean())
```

This the `s.loc[]` accepts an iterable with booleans in order to subset the LogRatio-`Series`

In order to make it more readable, I'd go for the following solution:

```
def quartile_subset(logratios,lower,upper):
    # some comment to describe what you are doing
    return logratios.loc[[True if v < logratios.quantile(q=upper) and v > logratios.quantile(q=lower) else False for v in logratios]]

df.groupby('Plate')['LogRatio'].transform(lambda s: quartile_subset(s,0.2,0.8).mean())
```

Comment: Good one. I used this to remove outliers from my Pandas data frame

Comment: best solution to avoid using fillna()